# Best practices: how to feed a set of long time series to a convolutional net for time series prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, convolution

Let us assume we run **N** experiments. During the experiments we collect measurements. In these measurements we have features and labels. We want to predict  the label **Y(t)** given a series of past features **X(t-1),X(t-2),...,X(t-T)**. I want to use Convolutional Neural Network for that. Here is what I thought to do to prepare the dataset for the CNN.

Our dataset is made of the data we collected for each experiment. Each experiement data is stored in a matrix where one dimension is equal to the features number and the other the time length. I divided each of the timeseries  in **time length/N** parts by selecting **N** time points:

[image]

then I can treat this chuncks of data coming from different experiments as my "images":

[image]

Then I feed (in batch) some images to the CNN. Since I know that the features are not correlated between each other I use a filter wich a row dimension of 1:

[image]

Is this making sense to you?